# Find Block Matrix Inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices

In this problem all blocks are $n\times n$.

(a) $A = \begin{bmatrix}I & 0 \\ C & I\end{bmatrix}$, where $C$ is $n \times n$ and $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity. What is $A^{−1}$?

(b) Now consider a general case $A = \begin{bmatrix}M & 0 \\ C & N\end{bmatrix}$, where $M$ and $N$ are invertible $n \times n$ matrices. What is $A^{-1}$?

Right now I am using the determinant method: In (a), I find the $\det(A)$ and $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ and get the inverse as $A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}I & 0 \\ -C & I\end{bmatrix}$; For (b) I am a bit confused; Also I am not sure if using the determinant method is right.

Comment: Right now I am using the determinant method: In (a), I find the det(A) and adj(A) and get the inverse as A^-1 = [I 0; -C I] ; For (b) I am a bit confused; Also I am not sure if using the determinant method is right

Comment: Could you please try to edit using latex ? what is "o;"  within your matrices ?

Comment: Here's a [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please use MathJax to typeset your question.

Comment: Please include your attempts in the question, not in the comments. Right now, your question is a "problem statement question" (contains nothing but the statement of the question). Such questions tend to be downvoted, closed, and not answered.

Comment: "o" is 0, sorry the format is a bit off

Comment: You can verify your $A^{-1}$ relatively easily by multiplying it to $A$, and verifying that it comes back to the $2n \times 2n$ identity matrix. For the general case, try finding a matrix $B = \begin{bmatrix} P_{11} & P_{21} \\ P_{12} & P_{22}\end{bmatrix}$ that multiplies with the given $A$ to give the identity. You could make the educated guess that assuming $P_{21} = 0$ will lead to a solution. This should lead to nice expressions for $P_{11}$ and $P_{22}$ in terms of $M$ and $N$, as well as an expression for $P_{12}$ in terms of $M, N, C$. Verify your guess by showing $AB = I$.

Answer (score 1):

You can search an inverse $B$ of the matrix $A$ in the following form:
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}B_1&B_2\\
B_3&B_4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $B_i$ is a $n\times n $ matrix (i=1,2,3,4).
You must have $AB=I$, which gives:
$$
B_1=M^{-1}, B_2=0,B_3=-N^{-1}CM^{-1}, B_4=N^{-1}.
$$
So,
$$
A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}M^{-1}&0\\
-N^{-1}CM^{-1}&N^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$